# Main battery is discharging with alternator running

Tags: cessna-172, lycoming

[image]

In my Cessna 172S, we had a problem about 'main battery discharge' after an hour of flight.

We tried doing wiring test on the connection at the master switch which ran from the alternator and performed a continuity test following the wiring diagram, but the result of the continuity test is ok and the problem still exists.

Also, we changed out a new ACU and alternator, but that didn't resolve the problem either.

Comment: Is the battery just going bad?

Comment: Is this your personal aircraft, or is it a club plane? If it's a club plane, or a rental, report it and let the club's mechanic deal with it.